# Stick the top div to top of the browser tab

Tags: html, css

```
<style type='text/css'>
body {
width:100%;
background:#097054;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#con {
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:80%;
}
#navbar {
background-color:#00F;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='navbar'>
<div id='con'>
Hey
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Whatever I try, the div navbar doesn't stick to the top of the page. When I try fixed or absolute positioning it fails to cover a little portion on the left. Either that, or it doesn't stick to top of the window at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#navbar {
   background-color:#00F;
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
}
```

When using position fixed also give it a width. I gave it width 100% so its the full width of the screen.

Okay so if you change the position to absolute it also works.

If you want to change the position to relative you also need to add this css

```
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

this clears preset styles on elements. usually the browser does this.

Comment: already tried that, but the background sticks out to the left. btw, is there any other way to do it without using position:fixed?

Comment: try now I forgot to include the left:0;

Comment: Hey I also added more in case you want to use different positions

Comment: This does fix the problem for the div, but, when a div appears below i am not able to make it cover the whole width

Comment: can you post exactly what you are doing in a fiddle so I can see.